# Stretch background using xloadimage

Tags: linux, desktop-customization

I want to stretch an image to fit my background using xloadimage. What's the proper argument to use when running the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to set up a background. I used this command:

```
feh --bg-max <path to image file>
```

`feh` is easier to use than `xloadimage`.

Comment: Do you know how to do this with `xloadimage`, though? I'm unable to use `feh`.